# Effiicient ways to count a streak of consecutive integers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have a vector containing only logical values, such as

```
V = [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
```

I would like to write a function in MATLAB which returns a 'streak' vector `S` for `V`, where S(i) represents the number of consecutive 1s in V up to but not including V(i). For the example above, the streak vector would be

```
S = [0 1 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0]
```

Given that I have to do this for a very large matrix, I would very much appreciate any solution that is vectorized / efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
S = zeros(size(V));
for i=2:length(V)
    if(V(i-1)==1)
        S(i) = 1 + S(i-1);
    end
end
```

The complexity is only **O(n)**, which I guess should be good enough.

For your sample input:

```
V = [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];
S = zeros(size(V));
for i=2:length(V)
    if(V(i-1)==1)
        S(i) = 1 + S(i-1);
    end
end
display(V);
display(S);
```

The result would be:

```
V =

     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0


S =

     0     1     0     1     0     1     2     3     4     0
```

Comment: I should have been more clear S(i) should *NOT* be tied to V(i) in any way. I've changed the example above, though I think that your solution works if you adjust the indices - right?

Comment: @BerkU.: Ok, but shouldn't `S(2)` and `S(4)` be `1` in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it completely vectorized with a couple intermediate steps:

```
V = [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];

Sall = cumsum(V);
stopidx = find(diff(V)==-1)+1;
V2=V;
V2(stopidx) = -Sall(stopidx)+[0 Sall(stopidx(1:end-1))];
S2 = cumsum(V2);

S = [0 S2(1:end-1)];
```

Afaik the only thing that can take a while is the `find` call; you can't use logical indexing everywhere and bypass the find call, because you need the absolute indices.

Answer (score 0):

It's outside the box - but have you considered using text functions? Since strings are just vectors for Matlab it should be easy to use them.

Regexp contains some nice functions for finding repeated values.